# Unable to use .keyCode in query selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am tyring to use .keyCode in javascript to select a key that is pressed but each time a key is pressed the console prints null

Here's the related css code

```
  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds\crash.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds\kick-bass.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds\snare.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds\tom-1.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds\tom-2.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds\tom-3.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds\sound-effect-thriller-1-108404.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds\tom-4.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds\flautatravessera-46420.mp3"></audio>
```

Here's the javascript code that I have tried

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    const audio=this.document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]')
    console.log(audio);
    audio.play();
   }
   )
```

It shows null at console.log(audio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks to delimit [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

Comment: Is there a easier method to type a backtick

Comment: @anshkumar What do you mean?

Comment: Well I cant find a backtick on my keyboard the the process shown in google was quite lengthy

Comment: @anshkumar Use string concatenation then: `'audio[data-key="'+ e.keyCode + '"]'`